# How do I access JavaScript objects in a parent window from an iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, iframe

I have a web page which contains a JavaScript variable called "myVariable".

Within this web page is an iframe which points to a second web page.

Both pages are within the same domain.

The page within the iframe needs to access "myVariable" which is defined in the parent web page.

I have successfully accessed this variable with Firefox using the following code:

```
document.defaultView.parent.myVariable
```

However, this does not work in Internet Explorer.....

How do I do this in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Yay! I needed to know this as well, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both pages are from the same domain (like you say), *window.top* or *window.parent* should work to get to the parent frame.

```
window.top.document.myVariable
```

Comment: Yep - just discovered window.yop myself - thought it was IE only, but firefox supports it as well so I've been able to remove branching code too. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 26.0,
Internet Explorer 11,
Chrome 32.0:

```
window.top.myVariable
```

window.top.*document*.myVariable did NOT work.

Comment: In my case both solutions did work fine (I choose the second one for the sake of brevity). Both of them solved my troubles trying to use “parent.myVariable” which worked in all browsers I tested except Firefox!